# MediaWiki template image dimension

Tags: image, templates, mediawiki

I'm trying to create a template like this

> {{#if: empty|
>   {{{Livello10|}}}||[[File:{{{Immagine10|}}}.png|40px]]||{{{Nome10|}}}

So if the three value will be empty, nothing will be display in the cells of the table, but the 40px is always present

MediaWiki 1.27.0 and I alreadye tried with Template:!, even if in this version is not needed

Edit: sorry, I'll try to explain better

[This link](http://shopheroesitalia.com/wiki/Template:TabellaOggetti) is the template page that I have to use and
[this is](http://shopheroesitalia.com/wiki/Prova2) an example of the output

As you can see, the "40px" is still visible, there's a way to hide it or if the value are empty, hide the whole row of the table?

Comment: From your description it is not very clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you please clarify your question or provide more context - some code around this block should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have two columns in a table, and you only want to populate them if `Livello10` is not empty? But you still want the cells to appear (i.e. you don't want to exclude the whole row)?

I think you'll have to have two `if` statements:

```
{|
| {{#if: {{{Livello10|}}} | [[File:{{{Immagine10|}}}.png|40px]] }}
| {{#if: {{{Livello10|}}} | {{{Nome10|}}} }}
|}
```

(I've put each cell on its own line, for clarity.)

Note that your `{{#if: empty|`...`}}` isn't doing what you might think: the string `empty` always equals True, and so only the first part is executed.

**Edit:**

Ah, that makes more sense. So, to hide the whole row, you'd do something like:

```
{|
! Livello !! Immagine !! Nome
|-
{{#if: {{{Immagine1|}}} | <!--
  -->{{!}} {{{Livello1|}}}<!--
  -->{{!}} [[File:{{{Immagine1}}}.png|40px]]<!--
  -->{{!}} {{{Nome1|}}}<!--
  -->{{!}}-
}}
|}
```

(The comment marks are just so the bits within the `if` statement can be indented, and note the use of the `{{!}}` trick for the pipes that indicate cells, to prevent those pipes being treated as part of the `if` statement.)

The '40px' problem you're having is because the File syntax resolves to `[[File:.png|40px]]` when `Immagine1` is empty; this renders as a red link saying `40px` which leads to an upload form for uploading the `.png` file (i.e. a filename with nothing before the dot).

If you just want to hide the 40px when there's no image, but still show the rest of the table, then my first answer above applies (i.e. wrap just the `[[File`...`]]` syntax in the `if` statement).

Comment: Thank you Sam, I've modified my first post, maybe it's a little more clear :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still I'm not able to make it works

I've put this

|{{#if: {{{ImmagineProssimo|}}} {{!}} [[File:{{{ImmagineProssimo}}}.png|40px]] {{!}} }}<br/>[[{{{Prossimo oggetto}}}]]

But in this page http://shopheroesitalia.com/wiki/Zanne_profane  still appear 40px and something els

Comment: The `{{!}}` only needs to be used when needing to output a pipe *within* the if statement. So you'd do:  `| {{#if: {{{ImmagineProssimo|}}} | [[File:{{{ImmagineProssimo}}}.png|40px]] }}<br/>[[{{{Prossimo oggetto}}}]]` Oh and you don't need to worry about the second if-statement pipe when you're not using the 'false' section of the statement.